# Sitecore multi-site patch file conflicts

Tags: sitecore

We have multiple site runing under one sitecore instance. Each has a patch file as follows

```
App_Config/Include/xxx/xxx.Asite.config
App_Config/Include/xxx/xxx.Bsite.config
```

When I check the configuration via `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`, I noticed some setting such as `<setting name="IgnoreUrlPrefixes">` always getting from the verylast config file in accending order (so my case it is `xxx.Zsite.config`) and applying to all sites.

How can I restrict that setting to that perticular site and force "Bsite" to take `<setting name="IgnoreUrlPrefixes">` setting from "`xxx.Bsite.config`" file instead `xxx.Zsite.config`

Comment: Can you post content of your config files for both sites?

Answer (score 3):

The `IgnoreUrlPrefixes` setting is one of the Sitecore settings that contains a pipe (`|`) separated list of arguments. Unfortunately the config patch architecture in Sitecore doesn't support adding/removing elements from such lists. It can only be replaced with a new value. That's why you get the value from the last processed file. This is, in my opinion, a design flaw of the config.

To work around this, you could maintain a complete list of values in a separate file, so that you don't have this setting in multiple files.

If that isn't a suitable solution, you could potentially override the `Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.IgnoreList` processor where you read your ignore list from another config location where you keep each ignore url as separate elements. Thereby you can patch individual elements in separate config files. However, such solution would not change the behavior of the static methods, such as `Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ShouldIgnoreUrl()`, so it might not work in all scenarios.